# Lightning Web Component error : afterRender threw an error in 'c:bearList' [e[Ei] is not a function]

Tags: trailhead, lightning-web-components

In trailhead Build a Bear-Tracking App with Lightning Web Components  (https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/lwc-build-flexible-apps/record-list?trail_id=build-lightning-web-components) when I edit bearList.js

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import ursusResources from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/ursus_park';
/** BearController.getAllBears() Apex method */
import getAllBears from '@salesforce/apex/BearController.getAllBears';
export default class BearList extends LightningElement {
    @wire(getAllBears) bears;
    appResources = {
        bearSilhouette: ursusResources +'/img/standing-bear-silhouette.png',
    };
}
```

then the component does not display anymore (was displaying with the previous version described in trailhead)
If I add it in the page builder I get the error

```
afterRender threw an error in 'c:bearList' [e[Ei] is not a function]
```

[image]

Comment: I figured it out on .html file bears must be replaced by bears.data

Comment: You should add that as an answer so that this question stands resolved.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot post answers from my account

Comment: @MarieTourne I'll do it for you! Accept my answer :)

Answer (score 5):

In your .html file `bears` must be replaced by `bears.data`.